# Why Oracle Left Join return null where there should be value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query that use left join 3 tables. but the results is null .

t1

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 000011 |
| AA | 000012 |
| AA | 000013 |
| BB | 000023 |

t2

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | AA |
| 01 | AA2 |
| 01 | AA3 |
| 02 | BB |

```
SELECT PMF.Col1,PMF.Col2 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(col1)
             FROM T1) TAS
    LEFT JOIN T2 PMF
        ON (TAS.col1 = PMF.col2)
    LEFT JOIN t3 BU
        ON (PMF.col1= BU.col1)
```

But if I run the query the number of result is correct but the value all null.
Result

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |
| null | null |

expected result should be

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | AA |
| 02 | BB |

Number of rows is correct but value is null
[ActualResult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqlN8.png)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: I would suspect the data. Are you sure, for example, that the values in one table or the other are not right-padded with spaces (for example, because they are of `CHAR` data type, instead of `VARCHAR2`)? Run `DESCRIBE T1` and `DESCRIBE T2` and share with us the exact data type and length of the columns involved in the join.

Comment: something else to check: committed vs uncommited transactions. Are both tables in the same schema, and is the query run from the same schema also? If not, are the inserts (or whatever other data manipulation) **committed** in the schemas that are NOT the schema from which you are running the query?

Comment: @mathguy both column is varchar2 as for padding or whitespaces they dont have any. yes both table is from the same schema. Also added a screenshot if it helps.

Comment: Am I missing something, or is the data for `t3` not shown in the question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah. data for t3 is not shown. didn't show it to simplify the question. or should I put it in.

Comment: I'd prefer to see the data, and the expected results with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at expected result, it seems like you need data from `t2` so you can use following query:

```
SELECT distinct PMF.Col1,PMF.Col2 
FROM T1 TAS
    JOIN T2 PMF
        ON (TAS.col1 = PMF.col2)
    LEFT JOIN t3 BU
        ON (PMF.col1= BU.col1)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. He didn't ask how to do something or another (even though perhaps he would indeed need that kind of help). Rather, he is asking why he is getting an unexpected result from what he **did** do. At first sight, the question makes sense - that result is not expected. There may be reasons, but they are not related to another way to solve his problem (or what we may think his problem is).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing.  The code has three tables, but you only show two in the question.

The issue in your query is the second `on` clause:

```
SELECT PMF.Col1,PMF.Col2 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(col1)
      FROM T1
     ) TAS LEFT JOIN
     T2 PMF
     ON TAS.col1 = PMF.col2 LEFT JOIN
     BU
     ON PMF.col1 = BU.col1;
--------^
```

The `ON` clause requires a match to `PMF`.  You are getting `NULL` values because there is no match.  The logic is a bit convoluted as well, because `PMF.col2` matches to `TAS`, not `PMF.col1`.

In any case, you should use a column from the first table, which I presume is:

```
SELECT PMF.Col1,PMF.Col2 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT col1
      FROM T1
     ) TAS LEFT JOIN
     T2 PMF
     ON TAS.col1 = PMF.col2 LEFT JOIN
     BU
     ON TAS.col1 = BU.col1;
```

Also note that using parentheses with `SELECT DISTINCT` is just silly.  `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all columns and expressions being selected.  The parentheses do nothing.